# Typescript generic initially infers then is set

Tags: typescript, generics

So I have this TS code:

```
type DefaultLevel = 'info' | 'error'; // Default log levels

interface LoggerOptions<CustomLevels extends string, Level extends CustomLevels | DefaultLevel> {
  customLevels?: Record<CustomLevels, number>
  level: Level
}

class Logger<CustomLevel extends string = '', Level extends CustomLevel | DefaultLevel = CustomLevel | DefaultLevel> {
  constructor(options?: LoggerOptions<CustomLevel, Level>) {
    // Initialization based on options
  }

  log(level: Level, message: string) {
    // Log message
  }
}

// Usage
const logger = new Logger({
  customLevels: {
    debug: 1,
    trace: 2,
  },
  level: 'debug'
});

logger.log('debug', '')
```

I first create a global `DefaultLevel` `union` `type` for my logger. Then I have a `LoggerOption` interface that has two generics `CustomLevels` and `Level`. `CustomLevels` allows me to create a custom level for my logger keeping everything type safe, while `Level extends CustomLevels | DefaultLevels` is needed to set the default level for my default logger. Doing `level: CustomLevels` did not work, hence the second generic.

My question arises in the log function of the class.

If I try to call logger.log('trace') I get a type error saying: 'Argument of type '"trace"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"debug"'.'

Hence I imagine that the `LoggerOptions` interface is setting the `Level` type value.

My question is, why within the `LoggerOptions` the level can be of type `'info' | 'error' | 'debug' | 'trace'` (desired behavior), but later in the code, variables of type `Level` can only be of the string type set within the `LoggerOptions`?

I know that within the log() method I could do something like this:

```
log(level: CustomLevel | DefaultLevel, message: string) {
    // Log message
}
```

But using the `Level` type would've been certainly much neater.

Comment: Looks like an XY problem. You had an issue, tried to solve it, the solution didn't work the way you wanted, and are now asking how to fix that solution. Instead I'd suggest going back and fixing the underlying issue, which seems to be about preventing inference from the `level` property. You can use `NoInfer` as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w6qo6W). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer, if not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you really want `Logger` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `Level` at all. That `Level` type will be inferred by the `level` property, which will almost certainly be narrower than `CustomLevels | DefaultLevel`.  If you want `Level` to be `CustomLevels | DefaultLevel` then use that type explicitly instead of trying to save it to another type parameter.

Indeed, your inclusion of that as a type parameter seems to have been meant just as a way to prevent `CustomLevels` from being inferred from the `level` property of the constructor input. You want

```
new Logger({ customLevels: { a: 1, b: 2 }, level: "c" });
```

to be an error, as opposed to inferring `CustomLevels` as `"a" | "b" | "c"`.  An additional type parameter can serve that purpose, but the "correct" tool for that job is to use [the intrinsic `NoInfer<T>` utility type](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-4/#the-noinfer-utility-type):

```
interface LoggerOptions<C extends string> {
  customLevels?: Record<C, number>
  level: NoInfer<C>
}
```

Now `Logger` only has to be generic in one type parameter:

```
class Logger<C extends string> {
  constructor(options?: LoggerOptions<C>) { }
  log(level: C | DefaultLevel, message: string) { }
}
```

You get the error you wanted:

```
new Logger({ customLevels: { a: 1, b: 2 }, level: "c" }) // error
```

As well as the proper behavior for `log()`:

```
const logger = new Logger({
  customLevels: {
    debug: 1,
    trace: 2,
  },
  level: 'debug'
});        

logger.log('trace', ''); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmBDArgG2AGQgNwqqAvFAOQCWAdvAPbFQA+JEATk1U8QNwBQXFwzSAMbQMVAOZjmAeTDBSVcgGcAPAGEoEAB79yAE0VRFwJhTEA+KAG8uUKIORGqAWyy5UigPwAuKACUIgmy6agA0UOTITgBGzGY2UKg4eD4AclQAkpTManEAvjyCqIiKBqIS2epaOvqGxqYW1raBSsbIgsBsABRUsvJK3lBlkkwycgoqqmYAlFZQ+bao4p2Jbj7qDHBIaJhJqGFOECWIkj5GJuRiM5ZzXPlc5BAA7oPiw53X9o4uu4o+14g+ACMYSiPgATHMwitklAAESCWFzGYAemRGhYbAK42ACVezEI4SeL3KTHe8U+HW+bl+Vnitl0ECiyDEQJCdKgxkQwnBbNsuV5CV2PmIDKZYmItym3B4XEWJIAdHLOsROcJiGFiMQpVBUVAqABrRAgIA)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just another quick question. Suppose now that I want a Level type that includes both the DefaultLevel and CustomLevel (C generic). I currently have a type: `type Level<C extends string> = DefaultLevel | C`, and within my class I use it as `log(level: Level<C>) => {}`. Is it good practice or is there a better way?

Comment: It seems reasonable to me, if you're going to reuse the type then defining it separately is good practice.